# Span and finite field

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

if $F$ is finite field ,and the span $\langle s_1,s_2,s_3 \rangle
$ generated by vector  $s_1,s_2,s_3$ ,then what mean the following equality
$$ \langle s_1,s_2,s_3 \rangle =F^4 .$$

thanks.

Comment: $F^4$ is the 4-dimensional vector space over $F$. Now compare with left-hand side.

Comment: if $F=\{0,1\}$ then the vector space $F^4$ contain all the vectors $$ \{0,0,0,0\}, \cdots ,\{1,1,1,1\}$$ .